# data.table rleid() function Julia equivalent

Tags: julia

Anyone know of a data.table::rleid() function that is available for Julia?

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4-2/topics/rleid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know any library function. But here you have two options.

#### Treats `missing` as a valid entry:

```
function rleid(x::AbstractVector)
    isempty(x) && return Int[]
    rle = similar(x, Int)
    idx = 1
    rle[1] = idx
    prev = x[1]
    for i in 2:length(x)
        this = x[i]
        if ismissing(this)
            if !ismissing(prev)
                prev = this
                idx += 1    
            end
        else
            if ismissing(prev) || this != prev
                prev = this
                idx += 1
            end
        end
        rle[i] = idx
    end
    rle
end
```

#### Skips `missing` placing `missing` in output vector:

```
function rleid_missing(x::AbstractVector)
    isempty(x) && return Union{Int,Missing}[]
    rle = similar(x, Union{Int, Missing})
    start_i = 1
    while start_i <= length(x) && ismissing(x[start_i])
        rle[start_i] = missing
        start_i += 1
    end
    if start_i <= length(x)
        idx = 1
        rle[start_i] = idx
        prev = x[start_i]
        start_i += 1
        for i in start_i:length(x)
            this = x[i]
            if ismissing(this)
                rle[i] = missing
            else
                if this != prev
                    prev = this
                    idx += 1
                end
                rle[i] = idx
            end
        end
    end
    rle
end
```

And here is a test:

```
Main> rleid([missing,3,4,4,missing,1,1,missing,missing,6])
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 3
 4
 5
 5
 6
 6
 7

Main> rleid_missing([missing,3,4,4,missing,1,1,missing,missing,6])
10-element Array{Union{Int64, Missings.Missing},1}:
  missing
 1
 2
 2
  missing
 3
 3
  missing
  missing
 4

Main> rleid_missing([missing,3,4,4,missing,1,1,missing,missing,1,6])
11-element Array{Union{Int64, Missings.Missing},1}:
  missing
 1
 2
 2
  missing
 3
 3
  missing
  missing
 3
 4
```

(in the last case observe that `missing` is treated as-if it were not present - it is easy to adjust the behavior if you wanted something different).

The beauty of Julia is that those functions will be fast - there no need to have them implemented in an external library written in C++.

Comment: WOW! Amazing response. I was just digging through the rleid source code to see if i could replicate it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Also - I love being able to write for loops in Julia without fearing slow run times

Comment: Thanks. I did not look at rleid source (that is why I did not know how they handle `missing`). Actually `missing` is tricky in both functions as comparing `missing` to anything produces `missing` not `Bool` so you have to be careful (unless you are sure your data does not have missing).

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as the for loop you wrote. Nice to see my shell of an idea confirmed. I am a R user primarily. I like writing for loops for functions though and writing a whole lot more of them using Julia. I think I am learning more by using Julia than R which is awesome. Types were new to me. But the Julia documentation is so good I for sure learned something!